# Installing Shiny on mac OS X

Tags: macos, r, rstudio, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to install Shiny on my MacBook and was wondering if anyone can help me in doing so.

I have tried to lookup instructions online but I find most of them are for Ubuntu.

I have developed static web-pages before, but they did not include .R code. I want to put up a simple webpage which allows users to selectively plot some data (e.g, plot Y v/s X for 1 value of third variable out of possible 9 values in a drop down menu).

I would be very thankful to the community if someone can guide me in setting up the Shiny server on my OS X machine or provide a basic example. I can run the examples provided with Shiny **from inside R Studio** but am not able to run them using a web-browser.

Thanks. - AK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ayesha Kalra, the shiny-server requires a linux machine as you can see in the readme.md file. You can not install the shiny server on a Mac.( at least not now )

> You'll need a Linux server, with the following prerequisites installed...

more information [shiny-server github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server)

If you want to deploy over the web you can apply for a free beta test account. [To register](https://rstudio.wufoo.com/forms/shiny-server-beta-program/)

Comment: I have written a homebrew formula for installing shiny-server on macOS
https://github.com/randy3k/homebrew-base/blob/shiny/Formula/shiny-server.rb